# Two-way binding between controller and directive with $watch in controller not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've come across a quite a few similar questions and tried them all with no success. I'm not sure if I'm doing this the "Angular way" so I might need to change my approach. In short I'm initialising a scoped variable from within a controller, the variable is then shared with the directive's scope. However when this value is changed as part of a user interaction the new value is not being synchronised with the controllers variable. My abbreviated code follows:

## Controller

The $watch method is only called once i.e. when the page loads.

```
.controller('NewTripCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.pickupLocation;
  $scope.dropoffLocation;

  $scope.$watch('dropoffLocation', function(oldVal, newVal) {
    console.log('dropofflocation has changed.');  
    console.log(oldVal);
    console.log(newVal);
  });
}])
```

## HTML

```
<div class="padding">
  <input ion-google-place type="text" class="ion-google-place" autocomplete="off" service="places" placeholder="Pickup Address" location="pickupLocation"></input>
</div>

<div class="padding">
  <input ion-google-place type="text" class="ion-google-place" autocomplete="off" service="places" placeholder="Dropoff Address" location="dropoffLocation"></input>
</div>
```

## Directive

```
angular.module('ion-google-place', [])
  .directive('ionGooglePlace', [
    '$ionicTemplateLoader',
    '$ionicBackdrop',
    '$q',
    '$timeout',
    '$rootScope',
    '$document',
    function ($ionicTemplateLoader, $ionicBackdrop, $q, $timeout, $rootScope, $document) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          location: '=location'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.locations = [];
          console.log('init');
          console.log(scope);
          console.log(attrs);
          // var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          var placesService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
          var searchEventTimeout = undefined;

          var POPUP_TPL = [
        '<div class="ion-google-place-container">',
        '<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">',
        '<label class="item-input-wrapper">',
        '<i class="icon ion-ios7-search placeholder-icon"></i>',
        '<input class="google-place-search" type="search" ng-model="searchQuery" placeholder="' + 'Enter an address, place or ZIP code' + '">',
        '</label>',
        '<button class="button button-clear">',
        'Cancel',
        '</button>',
        '</div>',
        '<ion-content class="has-header has-header">',
        '<ion-list>',
        '<ion-item ng-repeat="l in locations" type="item-text-wrap" ng-click="selectLocation(l)">',
        '{{l.formatted_address || l.description }}',
        '</ion-item>',
        '</ion-list>',
        '</ion-content>',
        '</div>'
          ].join('');

          var popupPromise = $ionicTemplateLoader.compile({
            template: POPUP_TPL,
            scope: scope,
            appendTo: $document[0].body
          });

          popupPromise.then(function (el) {
            var searchInputElement = angular.element(el.element.find('input'));

            // Once the user has selected a Place Service prediction, go back out
            // to the Places Service and get details for the selected location.
            // Or if using Geocode Service we'll just passing through
            scope.getDetails = function (selection) {
              //console.log('getDetails');
              var deferred = $q.defer();
              if (attrs.service !== 'places') {
                deferred.resolve(selection);
              } else {
                var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(element[0]);
                placesService.getDetails({
                    'placeId': selection.place_id
                  },
                  function(placeDetails, placesServiceStatus) {
                    if (placesServiceStatus == "OK") {
                      deferred.resolve(placeDetails);
                    } else {
                      deferred.reject(placesServiceStatus);
                    }
                  });
              }
              return deferred.promise;
            };


            // User selects a Place 'prediction' or Geocode result
            // Do stuff with the selection
            scope.selectLocation = function (selection) {
              // If using Places Service, we need to go back out to the Service to get
              // the details of the place.
              var promise = scope.getDetails(selection);
              promise.then(onResolve, onReject, onUpdate);
              el.element.css('display', 'none');
              $ionicBackdrop.release();
            };

            function onResolve (details) {
              console.log('ion-google-place.onResolve');

              scope.location = details;

              $timeout(function() {
                // anything you want can go here and will safely be run on the next digest.
                scope.$apply();
              })

              if (!scope.location) {
                element.val('');
              } else {
                element.val(scope.location.formatted_address || '');
              }              
            }
            // more code ...
      };
    }
  ]);
```

The $watch function only detects a change when the page loads but never again. What is the correct way to provide the controller with the value that the user enters into the directive's input element?

Comment: you have scope.location, in tpl is another location in ng-repeat

Comment: Good shout but I've updated it to have a different name and $watch still isn't firing.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this or try using `anonymous function`. Something like  `$scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.dropoffLocation}, function(){})` ..... Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [angular docs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) says:

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string, boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope.

This is a common issue when doing 2-way data binding with primitives. Try doing this same but try to share an object instead of a primitive.

i.e:

```
.controller('NewTripCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.pickupLocation = {location: ''};
    $scope.dropoffLocation = {location: ''};
    ...
```

Comment: Legend. I've gotten it working but I have to $watch "pickupLocation.location". Is there anyway to have changes to object fields/attibutes boil up to the object level?

Comment: sorry but I don't understand the question haha you can $watch pickupLocation without specifying location AFAIK BTW

Answer (score 1):

Here are your options

**Option#1 using ng-model**
with watch function in parent controller

```
<input ion-google-place type="text" class="ion-google-place" autocomplete="off" service="places" placeholder="Dropoff Address" ng-model="dropoffLocation"></input>
```

and in directive

```
scope: {
          location: '=ngModel'
        },
```

You don't need `Watch` here.

**Option#2 Through Object literal**

```
.controller('NewTripCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

 $scope.locationChanged = function(location){
    //you watch code goes here
 }

}



 <input ion-google-place type="text" class="ion-google-place" autocomplete="off" service="places" placeholder="Dropoff Address" location="dropoffLocation" location-changed="locationChanged(location)" ></input>
```

//directive scope

```
scope: {
          location: '=',
      locationChanged: '&'
        }
```

//in link function invoke parent controllers method as

```
scope.locationChanged({location:scope.location});
```

**Option#3 Through Function reference**

controllect and directives scope same as option#2

```
<input ion-google-place type="text" class="ion-google-place" autocomplete="off" service="places" placeholder="Dropoff Address" location="dropoffLocation" location-changed="locationChanged" ></input>


//in link function invoke parent controllers method as 

scope.locationChanged()(scope.location);
```

Option#2 is recommended for better readability.

watching variables should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for these. Please correct me if I'm wrong but with option 1 you would still need to watch the scoped variable if you wanted to trigger some functionality when it changed, right?